# Main timeline in a different path

Tags: homepage

I have a home.php file which I am using as my home page and it is showing a specific page.

In my index.php I have my main timeline. But when I access this page I get redirected to home.php.

How can I do that? To show my main timeline in a differente path then home. 
Something like mysite.com/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your `home.php` template file as `front-page.php`.

In WordPress parlance, "home" is the **Blog Posts Index**. The front page of the site is **Front Page**. Likewise, the `home.php` template file corresponds to the **Blog Posts Index** and the `front-page.php` template file corresponds to the **Site Front Page**, and the `is_home()` conditional returns true when on the **Blog Posts Index** while the `is_front_page()` conditional returns true when on the **Site Front Page**.

To summarize:

- **Site Front Page**: Front Page, `front-page.php`, `is_front_page()`
- **Blog Posts Index**: Home, `home.php`, `is_home()`

**EDIT:**

How to setup a static Page as Blog Posts Index:

1. Create two static Pages, with any arbitrary names (we'll call them "Front Page" and "Blog")
2. Go to: `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`
3. Set "Front Page Displays" to "Static Page"
4. Select "Front Page" in the dropdown for "Front page"
5. Select "Blog" in the dropdown for "Posts page"

Now (assuming you have configured pretty permalinks at `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`):

- Front Page URL: `www.example.com`
- Blog Posts Index URL: `www.example.com/blog/`

Comment: Thanks, and how would I access the blog posts index page? I mean the url?

Comment: See the edit/update to my answer, above.